# what classes have registered/claimed what URLs?

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-8

Using IBM Websphere 8.5, mix of ancient stuff (VG/EGL) that generates Java and JSP pages and actual written-by-human Java that uses javax.ws.rs.core.Application and related stuff.  Big massive code base, in multiple sub-projects and quite often we have URL conflicts when working on our local dev machines.  Additionally we are about to re-do a major portion and will need to run both code bases at once.

So... aside from gathering all code into one spot and recursively grepping for the `@Path` annotations, is there any way from either watching logs, checking Websphere admin interface, via code, etc. to determine exactly what URLs have been "claimed" and by what class?

Comment: I'd say that scanning for `@Path` annotations is the way, unless you want to hack into internal Websphere code.

Comment: `@Path` gives you only relative to context root part of the path. You would need to check what is the context root of the application. You can check that in the admin console. So if you use different context root you should not have conflicts. There is no way to list all 'claimed' URLs from logs or console.